# Angular load component styles after global styles

Tags: angular, sass

How can I load my scss variables, mixin, etc. in a component style in Angular?

My `src/styles.scss`

```css
$primary: #00aaff;

/* ... */

@mixin center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

and `src/app/mycomponent/mycomponent.component.scss`

```css
.content {
    @include center;
    color: $primary;
}
```

It doesn't know about the `@mixin` and `$primary` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem I just imported the scss file that I needed in this case:

```
@import "src/styles.scss";
```

Comment: I think --variable its more flexible and you should not import everywhere just a suggestion !

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead
File style.scss

```
root {
  --primary: #000;
}
```

File My.scss

```
.myClass {
  background: var(--primary);
}
```